# How do I add addons to Minecraft Bedrock edition on an Xbox One by converting a USB hard drive to be used for a computer?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, minecraft-addons

I found a program to convert the hard drive to be able to be used for a computer. However, how do I open the files? One of them is Microsoft.MinecraftUWPConsole_8wekyb3d8bbwe.UWA, which is probably Minecraft, but I cannot open it.

I have tried notepad and opening the file as an archive with 7zip but both did not work.

Comment: What makes you think you need to edit/start files to be able to add addons?

Comment: I don't have Bedrock on the Xbox to check, but I'd suggest peeking at the [wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Adding_mods_to_Xbox_One).

Comment: @Penquin can I magically add the addons from my computer to the xbox? 
I must put the files from my computer onto a hard drive and move it onto the xbox in the com.mojang\behavior_packs

Comment: @Renegade that way is outdated, because microsoft decided to remove file explorer. Also, "This tutorial is no longer possible to use as the UFO app has been delisted from the Microsoft Store." Even though I have it, it no longer functions because file explorer has been removed

Answer (score 1):

Heres an easier way, go into microsoft store and get "Mc addons' or sum like that, then go into internet explorer on the xbox, find a bedrock edition addon, go into mc addons and click import, then find your addon.

NOTE: Some addons may not work